# MVC Dependency Injection Autofac, where to specify dependencies

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a ASP.NET MVC Web App with the following layers

UI Layer -> Service Layer -> Data Access Layer -> Database

Each layer is a separate project.  Plus there is another project for each layer (apart from the UI Layer) which contains only the interfaces.

My question is, when building the Autofac container I specify the dependencies (Service Layer, Data Access Layer) along with the interfaces, in the OwinStartup Class.  Is this the proper place to do this?  If not how do I separate this.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/ioc-di-why-do-i-have-to-reference-all-layers-assemblies-in-entry-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to compose your container on the application level, e.g. using an OwinStartup class or similar. That said, I usually separate out the dependency setup for each assembly/project into their own [Autofac module](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules). This way, the assemblies become more self-contained. The application level setup also becomes much cleaner, its only responsibility is pulling in the various modules and building the container.